# Is there a delay before other transactions see a commit if using asynchronous commit in Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm looking into optimizing throughput in a Java application that frequently (100+ transactions/second) updates data in a Postgresql database. Since I don't mind losing a few transactions if the database crashes, I think that using **asynchronous commit** could be a good fit.

My only concern is that I don't want a delay after commit until other transactions/queries see my commit. I am using the default isolation level "Read committed".

So my question is: Does using **asynchronous commit** in Postgresql in any way mean that there will be delays before other transactions see my committed data or before they proceed if they have been waiting for my transaction to complete? (As mentioned before, I don't care if there is a delay before my data is persisted to disk.)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that this is the behavior you're looking for.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-async-commit.html

> Selecting asynchronous commit mode means that the server returns success as soon as the transaction is logically completed, before the
>   WAL records it generated have actually made their way to disk. This
>   can provide a significant boost in throughput for small transactions.

The WAL is used to provide on-disk data integrity, and has nothing to do about table integrity of a running server; it's only important if the server crashes. Since they specifically mention "as soon as the transaction is logically completed", the documention is indicating that this does not affect table behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the key here is "logically completed", and I interpret the documentation in the same way as you. Let's see if someone really can confirm this, otherwise I will go with this assumption for now.

Comment: If it matters that much, why not just test it?

Comment: Is it possible to set it per Table or Tablespace basis ?